# Error: (using List class) Index was outside the bounds of array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a project and I'm a beginner in programming in c#, and somehow there is a problem that I cannot solve. How it happened: In executing the code, the application launches successfully but an exception
shows that the "Index was outside the bounds of array". Afterwards, I was able to click items on a listbox and it shows the second object on the textbox. So... It seems like it works(clicking on listbox's item) but I cannot figure out why it would throw an exception about the array. Beneath is the current code that I have.

**Update:I sincerely apologize. I uploaded the wrong code. It is suppose to be this code:

Code:

```
struct studentInfo
{  
  public string studentID;
  public string major;
}  

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<studentInfo> studentList = new List<studentInfo>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void ReadInputFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line = "";

            studentInfo student = new studentInfo();

            char[] delimiter = { ',' };

            inputFile = File.OpenText("Student Info.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                string[] token = line.Split(delimiter);

                student.studentID = token[0];
                student.major = token[1];

                studentList.Add(student);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void DisplaystudentID()
    {
        foreach (studentInfo student in studentList)
        {
            studentInfoListBox.Items.Add(student.studentID);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayNames()
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadInputFile();

        DisplaystudentID();
    }

    private void studentInfoListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = studentInfoListBox.SelectedIndex;

        majorTextBox.Text = studentList[index].major;


    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does it throw that exception and what is the exact type and message of the exception?

Comment: Perhaps one of the lines doesn't have a comma? For instance, the very last line in the file, is that the last line *with* text, or is there perhaps a blank line there?

Comment: Hello! The line that it throw the exception was the catch statement. The catch statement with the MessageBox. The message of the exception stated like this: "Cannot evaluate expression because a native expression is on top of the call stack".

Comment: On a side note, you are only creating a single `PhoneBookEntry` object for your while clause. That way, you will end up with a single object being added to the `phoneList` again and again but the reference never changes. That way you will end up with a list full of the same (last) entry of your `while` loop. Put the `PhoneBookEntry entry = new PhoneBookEntry();` line inside the while loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to guard `SelectedIndex`, when controls are initially created SelectedIndex is set to `-1`

```
private void nameListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(nameListBox.SelectedIndex >=0)
    {
         int index = nameListBox.SelectedIndex;

         phoneLabel.Text = phoneList[index].phone;
    } 
}
```

Comment: No problem. I'm glad this helped you.

Comment: `nameListBox.SelectedIndex == -1` is typical, when *no items* are selected.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that SelectedIndexChanged is ran at the start (before you select anything) and at that point nameListBox.SelectedIndex would be -1 and you can't get the "negative 1 position's item" in a list. I would make sure that the selected index is valid

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx
"A zero-based index of the currently selected item.A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected."

I would change the code as such:

```
private void nameListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = nameListBox.SelectedIndex;
    if(index !=-1)
    {
        phoneLabel.Text = phoneList[index].phone;
    }
    // else do nothing, the selected item didn't really change, it's just called for the first time, think of it as the control saying "hey i just got created and i'm notifying you that the selected item is now nothing"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ronan~ I see how this logic works. I'll take a note of this as part of my programming education in c#. :D

Answer (score 1):

The only array handling you have in your program is this:

```
entry.name = tokens[0];
entry.phone = tokens[1];
```

Therefore the reason is that one of the lines in your text file does not have a comma, so `tokens` does not have 2 parts.

A common reason for this is simply having a file that has a linefeed after the final *real* entry, thereby having an empty line as the last line.

I would simply handle this here:

```
if (tokens.Length < 2)
    continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't let us know where exactly the exception is occurred but as I see it might be in this part

```
line = inputFile.ReadLine();

string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

entry.name = tokens[0];
entry.phone = tokens[1];
```

If your line is empty or doesn't have "," you will get exception in the next line

Also you need to check the access to list in the `index` location in `nameListBox_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

"Index was outside the bounds of array" exception occurs when you try to access an element which is not exits in the list. I believe you are getting this exception when you are click on the last item on your list.

In your **nameListBox_SelectedIndexChanged** method you one of following.

```
int index = nameListBox.SelectedIndex -1;
```

or

```
phoneLabel.Text = phoneList[index-1].phone;
```